# how to build only the PR from github in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, github-webhook

I have jenkins setup using the 'Github Pull Request Builder' and for the most part its great.  However extra builds are being triggered referencing closed PR's.
For example if create PR 8, it will also build:

origin/pr/7/head

origin/pr/8/merge

How can I stop it from doing these 2 extra builds?

Answer (score 0):

Here check the docs.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin#creating-a-job

> If you just want to build PRs, set refspec to +refs/pull/${ghprbPullId}/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/${ghprbPullId}/*